# Why does qconf -mq does not recognize an entry like -sq?

Tags: configuration, sungridengine

Good day,

Using SGE 8.6.18, I get correct output with `qconf -sq q@hostname.fqdn...com`

I want to change the qtype of the queue with the `-mq` option as `qconf -sq q@hostname.fqdn...com` but I get this error:
Cluster queue entry "q@hostname.fqdn...com" does not exist

I checked the output of `qconf -sm` and I am listed as a manager of the farm.

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

The 'does not exist' simply means there is no individual queue, for each machine. I found out there is only on queue, named 'q'. Therefore I must use `qconf -mq q`.